# Public properties not showing in metadata file in c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have added a few public properties to my already created class. When I call this class in another place the newly added properties are not showing, and when I go to the definition with class name, direct to the metadata non-editable file, my newly added properties are not there either. Anyone have idea about my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it looks like you haven't updated the referenced assembly in the project that uses it. Look at the properties of this assembly in the properties inspector and you will see the path from where it was referenced. Now go ahead and update this assembly with the new version.

Comment: i didnt get ur asnwer yet. can u guide me how to go to the properties inspector, actualy i am new to OOP programing in c#.

Comment: @Sunethpiumal, click on the assembly in the `References` node and then press `F4`. A window containing properties of this assembly will show in Visual Studio where you can inspect those properties. Now look at the `Path` property.

Comment: i got dat window u have mentioned, and the only one problem i have how to update the assembly now? if u r not busy right now, can u guide me to this only, i am realy appreciate ur commitment..